# How to prove bilinear transformation is an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra

If you have a transformation mapping 2 finite-demensional vector spaces, through say $T(V,W)$, to a $n\times m$ matrix, how would you prove its an isomorphism?

First I think I'd prove it's surjective.

Then do I prove $\ker(T) = \{0\}$ or do I prove 1-1?

Comment: For linear transformations $T$, $\ker T = \{0\}$ is equivalent to injectivity. I strongly recommend you prove this to yourself, as the particular intuition here is very valuable.

Comment: Okay, now I need to figure out how to prove ker$T$ = {0}

Comment: Do you mean, your map is from $T(V, W)$ to the space of $n \times m$ matrices?

Comment: To a matrix of size n x m